# The PackageKit Deamon has crashed

Tags: updates

I can't update on Kubuntu 18.10. I have 20 packages, when updating from GUI i get: 
The PackageKit Deamon has crashed

From terminal:
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y I get:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

I tried this without luck: https://itsfoss.com/could-not-get-lock-error/comment-page-5/

The day after i get:

E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure
-a' to correct the problem.

Running: sudo dpkg --configure -a

```
Setting up snapd (2.37.1+18.10) ...
snapd.failure.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
snapd.snap-repair.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
```

systemctl status snapd.service

```
● snapd.service - Snappy daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; enabled; v
   Active: deactivating (stop-sigterm) (Result: timeout)
 Main PID: 22246 (snapd)
    Tasks: 12 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 268.4M
   CGroup: /system.slice/snapd.service
           ├─22246 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd
           ├─22319 apparmor_parser --replace --write-cache -O no
           └─22320 apparmor_parser --replace --write-cache -O no

Feb 13 11:46:58 xxxx systemd[1]: Starting Snappy daemon...
Feb 13 11:46:58 xxxx snapd[22246]: AppArmor status: apparmor is 
Feb 13 11:46:59 xxxx snapd[22246]: helpers.go:145: error trying 
Feb 13 11:46:59 xxxx systemd[1]: snapd.service: Start operation
```

journalctl -xe

```
-- Subject: Unit snapd.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit snapd.service has finished shutting down.
Feb 13 11:47:47 xxxx systemd[1]: snapd.service: Found left-over 
Feb 13 11:47:47 xxxx systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean 
Feb 13 11:47:47 xxxx systemd[1]: snapd.service: Found left-over 
Feb 13 11:47:47 xxxx systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean 
Feb 13 11:47:47 xxxx systemd[1]: Starting Snappy daemon...
```

I can't run: `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
I get: `dpkg: error: dpkg frontend is locked by another process`

```
lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

everything is dead.

I believe I have to reinstall a new lock, I don't know how to do so?

```
sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I entered terminal as root via restore mode by holding shift down under startup and rebootet. 
`sudo dpkg --configure -a` worked from terminal afterwords.